# How to add a menu in a tablayout

Tags: android

I want this in my tablayout but i cant get it there, in only works in the empty activity, any idea?[image]

Code used in the Empty activity .java

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return true;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide the code for the activity with tabs (the activity that is not empty)

Comment: You also need to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in your activity

Comment: I have tried calling setHasOptionsMenu(true) in the method oncreateview in all the fragments but it doesnt work.